# Hidden login script

Tags: macos, bash, script, iterm, login-items

I have a bash shell script that runs on login. Even though I selected the "hide" checkbox in system preferences, iTerm still shows while running it.

How do I completely hide it?

Answer (score 4):

Try to run the script with launchd instead. Save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>some.label</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/path/to/script</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The script should be run the next time you log in. Make sure the script is executable (`chmod +x /path/to/script`) and starts with an interpreter line (like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

You can also replace the `Program` key with for example

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>say</string>
  <string>a</string>
</array>
```

or

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>bash</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>say a;ls|say</string>
</array>
```

See `man launchd.plist` or http://osxnotes.net/launchd.html for more information.

Comment: What is the label thing?

Answer (score 1):

Worked great to solve the Mavericks bluetooth always discoverable nightmare using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

defaults -currentHost write com.apple.Bluetooth DiscoverableState -bool no

launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist 2> /dev/null

launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```